# How to calculate formula for every value in an array?

Tags: python, numpy, formula

Im trying to get to understand how to use numpy for calculating a formula for different times. The way the code is written gives all the values where y is bigger than 0. I am experimenting how to get the values for all y's.

Is there someone who can explain me the part:  `ft = t * [y >= 0.0 ]`. How do i use the parts within the brackets?

```
from numpy import *

g = 10.0
h0 = 10.0

t = arange(0, 10.1 ,0.1)
y = h0 - 0.5*g*t*t

ft = t * [y >= 0.0 ]


print(ft)
```

This is the output, but I would like to see all the values calculated. So i experimented a bit but i could not figure it out how to do it and how the; [y >= 0.0] part exactly works.

```
[[0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]]
```

If i use [y] instead of [y >= 0.0] i get the following:

```
[[ 0.000000e+00  9.950000e-01  1.960000e+00  2.865000e+00  3.680000e+00
   4.375000e+00  4.920000e+00  5.285000e+00  5.440000e+00  5.355000e+00
   5.000000e+00  4.345000e+00  3.360000e+00  2.015000e+00  2.800000e-01
  -1.875000e+00 -4.480000e+00 -7.565000e+00 -1.116000e+01 -1.529500e+01
  -2.000000e+01 -2.530500e+01 -3.124000e+01 -3.783500e+01 -4.512000e+01
  -5.312500e+01 -6.188000e+01 -7.141500e+01 -8.176000e+01 -9.294500e+01
  -1.050000e+02 -1.179550e+02 -1.318400e+02 -1.466850e+02 -1.625200e+02
  -1.793750e+02 -1.972800e+02 -2.162650e+02 -2.363600e+02 -2.575950e+02
  -2.800000e+02 -3.036050e+02 -3.284400e+02 -3.545350e+02 -3.819200e+02
  -4.106250e+02 -4.406800e+02 -4.721150e+02 -5.049600e+02 -5.392450e+02
  -5.750000e+02 -6.122550e+02 -6.510400e+02 -6.913850e+02 -7.333200e+02
  -7.768750e+02 -8.220800e+02 -8.689650e+02 -9.175600e+02 -9.678950e+02
  -1.020000e+03 -1.073905e+03 -1.129640e+03 -1.187235e+03 -1.246720e+03
  -1.308125e+03 -1.371480e+03 -1.436815e+03 -1.504160e+03 -1.573545e+03
  -1.645000e+03 -1.718555e+03 -1.794240e+03 -1.872085e+03 -1.952120e+03
  -2.034375e+03 -2.118880e+03 -2.205665e+03 -2.294760e+03 -2.386195e+03
  -2.480000e+03 -2.576205e+03 -2.674840e+03 -2.775935e+03 -2.879520e+03
  -2.985625e+03 -3.094280e+03 -3.205515e+03 -3.319360e+03 -3.435845e+03
  -3.555000e+03 -3.676855e+03 -3.801440e+03 -3.928785e+03 -4.058920e+03
  -4.191875e+03 -4.327680e+03 -4.466365e+03 -4.607960e+03 -4.752495e+03
  -4.900000e+03]]
```

I would like to know how i can use numpy to calculate at once all the outcomes of a formula for different time intervals.

Thanks,

Comment: The question is solved. I was thinking wrong but it is now clarified. I was expecting to get all the times during the fall But ofcourse i would get that if i just printed out the time:array. tnx for help we can close this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y >= 0.0` gives you an array of Booleans which contain True/False depending on the fulfillment of the condition `y >= 0.0`. When you enclose it within `[]` as `[y >= 0.0]`, you get a list which contains a single array of Booleans, as pointed out by @nicola in the comments below.

```
[array([ True,  True,  True,  True, True, False, False, False,...
   ... False, False, False, False])]
```

Now you multiply this with your `arange` array which will give you 0 when the right hand side of `*` operator is `False` and will give you the actual value from the `arange` when the right hand side of `*` operator is `True`

Comment: Actually `[y >= 0.0 ]` gives you a `list` with just an element being the array you are talking about.

Comment: Thankyou for the fast response! This makes it more clear. I know how it works now. Basically i first calculate the y values for every t above ft = t * [y >= 0.0 ],  after that i only multiply with the 1's that are standing for the true booleans.

Comment: @nicola : Technically, you are absolutely right. let me rephrase my wordings. Thanks. I edited

Comment: @Sheldore This was just to point out that the use of `[` here is pretty strange, since it creates an extra dimension on `ft`, which is not clear to me if it's intended.

Answer (score 0):

The array [y >= 0.0] produces and array of booleans.  i.e. 1 if y>=0 and 0 if not.  That array of 1's and 0's is then multiplied by t.

It is not clear to me from your question however, what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: i can understand it was not clear. I wanted to get the outcome where all times are visable. But ofcourse this is just the time array, so i was thinking wrong. My question is solved